# Is it possible to modify master pages and web parts from a .wsp file?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, solution-package

Is it possible to extract the various projects from a wsp file to work on say the masterpages, web parts and other custom user controls just like I would in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your WSP as a project in Visual Studio 2010. This will give you a starting project layout, which you can modify and recompile/repackage.

Simply do New Project and then choose the type for importing WSP (I don't have the exact name handy but it's obvious when you read it :P)

Comment: Thanks a ton Louis! I am assuming that if I just save the changes I make in VS2010 the wsp gets updated automatically?

Comment: Not the original WSP, you will get a brand new VS2010 project and you can just repackage it in its own WSP (with the same name if you wish)

Answer (score 1):

it a cab file, rename it to .zip or register your favorite archive manager.

Then you can view/edit its content.

When you are done, recab it.