# How to edit web part from wsp solution

Tags: development, web-part, visual-studio, solution-package

I have wsp files that contain some web parts that I need to change the functionality of.  Without the actual solution or project files, using just the wsp, is it possible to edit them?

I changed the files to cab's, and used IZArc to open them.  I have a dll, xml files, and .webpart files.

I created a new project, importing from a solution package, as per the directions here: [Is it possible to modify master pages and web parts from a .wsp file?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39071/is-it-possible-to-modify-master-pages-and-web-parts-from-a-wsp-file), but all I get are the .webpart files, no c#.

Is it possible to change the c# files from these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can decompile the DLL with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or any other [decompile tools](https://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=decompile%20tools%20C#&rlz=) and or [import the WSP into Visual Studio](http://ahmedmadany.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/importing-sharepoint-solution-package-wsp-into-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: I used Reflector, thank you, saved me weeks of having to rebuild web parts.