# How can I build a Visual Studio 2010 solution from wsp?

Tags: visual-studio, sandbox-solution, solution-package

I've inherited a site with a Sandbox Solution but no documentation nor the original solution package.  How can I extract the .wsp to get the solution?  I tried renaming it to a .cab file and extracting it and importing the solution to Visual Studio.  In both cases, I'm missing the .cs files for the Web Parts. I can only see the .webpart file and the .elements file.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83071/how-to-edit-web-part-from-wsp-solution) a few months ago.  Here is the answer I got:

After extracting the dll files from the .cab, you can decompile the DLL with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or any other [decompile tools](https://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&q=decompile%20tools%20C#&rlz=) and or [import the WSP into Visual Studio](http://ahmedmadany.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/importing-sharepoint-solution-package-wsp-into-visual-studio-2010/).

I've been using JetBrains dotPeek, and I've been satisfied by it.

Comment: Thank you!  My Google skills must have been lacking this morning. Sorry for the duplicate!